# An exceptional sentence

Tags: grammar

> The earth moves in a way such as to orbit round the sun.

- Is this sentence correct?

  If it is then say something about the exceptional part-"such as to orbit round the sun".

Comment: It's a rather strange thing to say (I can't put my finger on exactly *why*, but it seems a bit like saying *An apple falls in such a way as to get closer to the ground*). But *grammatically* it seems fine to me - though as per my example, I'd move ***such*** leftward so it more clearly modifies ***a way***.

Comment: Exceptional? It's an exceptionally long way to say "the earth orbits the sun."

Comment: Then again, it's a really nice iambic heptameter, which may explain the odd position of "such" that @FumbleFingers pointed out.

Comment: @Digital: Quite. If it *didn't* orbit the Sun (or maybe Jupiter or Saturn), firstly Earth probably wouldn't still be in the Solar System, and secondly we almost certainly wouldn't be around to discuss how to talk about its motion.

Comment: It's technically correct, and in a particular context (where the motion of various things is being discussed, eg) it might even be the "right" way to say it.

Comment: As a single sentence this is a very stilted formulation.

Comment: It is grammatical and is correct. But it has too many unnecessary, redundant, superfluous words.

Comment: It is a construction which would normally be used for something more complex and less predictable, such as 'He spoke in such a way as to make his entire audience feel angry and upset'. you would NOT USE IT for an everyday thing such as 'He moved his hand in such a way as to pick up his knife and fork'. Except that if you were talking about someone who had been paralysed, and they had not previously lifted a knife and fork for twenty years; and it was being done with the aid of one of these new devices that connects the brain directly to a mechanical arm etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this sentence is incorrect because it implies cause and effect. It implies that the earth moves in a particular way in order that it may orbit the sun.

> Cause: earth moves
>    Effect: earth orbits the sun

In fact the movement **is** the orbiting. So you can say one of two things:

> The earth moves round the sun.
>  The earth orbits the sun.

The earth also moves by spinning on its axis but as far as I'm aware (shaky physics) this does not **cause** it to orbit the sun.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all those words, it's easier to understand that

The earth moves in such a way as to orbit round the sun.

Comment: I think the OP understands the meaning of the sentence, but finding it strange decided to ask about it. I don't think your answer really addresses this concern. Perhaps you can edit in more information? BTW, welcome to ELU. Please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm a rank newbie to ELU and to stack in general so there's bound to be some mismatch. I believe the original wording was awkward but that there was a desire for some reason to include all those words and to leave the reader with just a vague notion of Earth and Sun movement, hence my suggested change of word order. If I wanted to be precise as you were, I'd also have to include axial precession and the galaxy's movement in the universe.

Comment: drb - we all were newbies once. I understand your answer better now. I thought about adding the axial wobble and the movement of the galaxy through the universe, but the latter reminds me that in a few short billion years, we're going to collide with the Andromeda galaxy (unless I'm wrong?!), and that makes me sad, so I didn't include it. Anyway, I hope you stick around. :)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. The downvoter hasn't given a reason, but it may be because a good answer would explain **why** your version is “easier to understand.” That’s what the question actually asks for, after all.